# Programmatically set property of bean

Tags: spring, javabeans

I am trying to figure out how I can adjust the "period" property of the "destroyWorldTask" bean that is defined like this in my list of beans. Is this possible? What is the proper way to do this?

```
<bean id="mytimerfactory"
  class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="daemon" value="true"/>
    <property name="myTimerTasks">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask" id="destroyWorldTask">
                <property name="delay" value="100"/>
                <property name="period" value="10000/>
                <property name="runnable">
                    <bean class="com.scene7.is.util.SafeRunnable">
                        <constructor-arg ref="destroyWorld"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
           </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible answers:
1. If you want the "period" property be set somewhere in the program, you don't need to set in the context configuration. (Which I think not suitable for you, as you are using a spring class, not yours).
2. Extend from **org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask** and make your edition of the class, something like:

```
public MyTimeScheduledTimerTast extends ScheduledTimerTask{
     //...
}
```

and set that property in your program. (Now it's in your hand)
Then update your context configuration like this:

```
<bean id="mytimerfactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
<property name="daemon" value="true"/>
<property name="myTimerTasks">
    <list>
        <bean class="myPackage.MyScheduledTimerTask" id="destroyWorldTask">
              <!-- Set those properties that are not set in your program -->
       </bean>
    </list>
</property>
</bean>
```

Comment: But don't I need to somehow grab the bean instance of MyTimeScheduledTimerTask and then call its setPeriod?

Comment: As you are inheriting your class from spring scheduledTimerTask, you can add as many property as you like and one of them could be your desired property. You can set it in your program by instantiating a bean from your class and do what you want.